# sync code between IDE running in PC with code in backend UNIX machine

Tags: python, ide

Is there any  good python IDE  which can  be run  on  WINDOWS machine  and directly edit  file on UNIX  so  the effort  of  maintaing  copies of  code  both on PC and  UNIX host can be avoided . If  am  hoping  if   IDE  can't  do it  by itself  there  should  be a seemless file transfer mechanism

Comment: You can use`git` or `samba` server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to edit remote files from the editor on a personal PC, here are the some ways to have a look:

- [Atom](https://atom.io) with [remote-edit](https://atom.io/packages/remote-edit) addition
- [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) with [nppftp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp) addition

For a broader answer [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/796/is-there-an-ide-i-could-use-to-edit-code-from-a-personal-computer-over-the-netwo) and [this](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-best-code-editor-to-edit-files-on-a-remote-host-I-use-Ubuntu-by-the-way) might help.